# How to change the Results file name during runtime in JMeter?

Tags: jmeter

I have a sampler inside my test plan. I also have a Simple Data Writer to save requests and responses.

I have entered "Results.xml" to filename field in Simple Data Writer. When I run the test plan, a text file gets generated in the designated path.

Is it possible to change the filename to "Threadgroupname_SamplerName_Results.xml" at runtime?

For example, I have renamed my Thread group to "Search" and the sampler to "CurrencyConverter". Is it possible to save the result in format "Search_CurrencyConverter_Results.xml" during runtime?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to save request/response data only from this Sampler from this Thread Group?

Comment: Why do you want to rename file at runtime?

Answer (score 8):

You can use variable placeholders and the __time function in the filename input field to have it dynamically set/changed at runtime. Something like this:

```
${results.dir}/myresultfile_${__time(YMDHMS)}.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [jmeter bugzilla](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55012), it is not possible to include the thread group name in the filename because "ResultCollector is initialized in StandardJMeterEngine thread before launch of any ThreadGroup so `ctx.getThreadGroup()` will return null."